# Embed not being sent

Tags: python, discord.py, praw

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import praw

cl = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = "",
                    client_secret = "",
                    username = "",
                    password = "",
                    user_agent = "")
@cl.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is ready, get ready to do wutever u want with it")

@cl.command()
async def meme(ctx, amount=50, subr="memes", filter="top"):
 all_submission = []
 subreddit = reddit.subreddit("subr")
 subs = subreddit.filter(limit = amount)
 for submission in subs:
   all_submission.append(submission)
 random_sub = random.choice(all_submission)
 name = random_sub.title
 url = random_sub.url
 em = discord.embed(title = name)
 em.set_image = url
 await ctx.send(embed=em)
 print("embed sent")


cl.run("")
```

when I was running this nothing showed up but when I debugged it and !meme in discord it was showing me this traceback error thing

```
It appears that you are using PRAW in an asynchronous environment.
It is strongly recommended to use Async PRAW: https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io.
Ignoring exception in command meme:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 20, in meme
    subs = subreddit.filter(limit = amount)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/base.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    self._fetch()
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py", line 584, in _fetch
    data = self._fetch_data()
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py", line 581, in _fetch_data
    return self._reddit.request("GET", path, params)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 885, in request
    return self._core.request(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 330, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 228, in _request_with_retries
    response, saved_exception = self._make_request(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 185, in _make_request
    response = self._rate_limiter.call(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/rate_limit.py", line 33, in call
    kwargs["headers"] = set_header_callback()
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 283, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 425, in refresh
    self._request_token(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 158, in _request_token
    raise OAuthException(
prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request
```

This is the error thing I was talking about and it is very weird like telling me to download async praw which I have never had a problem with and pls help it is needed

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be a discord.py issue, it appears to be related to the praw 0auth flow.

According to the traceback, there's an authentication issue in your praw credentials. Double, triple, and quadruple check your authentication credentials  and flow with the [workflow and methodology in the docs](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/authentication.html)